# crontab not working with shell script

Tags: shell, cron

i have one shell script which i want to run every hour.

My crontab looks like shown below

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
02 * * * * root run-parts /Weather/run.sh
```

but its not running every hour.
2 days before i had written same code in /etc/cron.d/0hourly file that time it was working perfectly but suddenly now it stopped working, then i tried writting it in crontab but its not running. 
i checked the crontab running status it gave me following

```
crond (pid  4487) is running...
```

My log file at /var/log/root is showing like

```
Apr  9 06:02:01 sandbox crond[4487]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Apr  9 06:02:01 sandbox crond[4487]: (crontab) ORPHAN (no passwd entry)
```

Am i doing something wrong??
Is there any step i missed?
in which file should i write code either in **/etc/crontab** or **/etc/cron.d/0hourly**

Please help me resolve this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -2):

The leading 0, '02' is not necessary. I don't now if that will cause an error. There also seems to be a single tick at the end of your line. I like to explicitly set the shell with:

```
2 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/full/path/to/script >> /full/path/to/log.log 2>&1'
```

Comment: thanks for reply joncon, i tried command u shwned but no luck its stil the same.its not working yet and log file remains same and tick at the end of line is just printo while writing it here.

Comment: What i the exact line of your cronjob and does it work when you run it by hand?

Comment: Run.sh script contains wget command which streams the data from weatherunlocked.com to json format file, later it starts the flume agent to stream the json file to HDFS. it contains following things.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
if [ -f /Weather/Docs/WeatherOutput.json]
then
  rm -f /Weather/Docs/WeatherOutput.json
fi
url="http://api.weatherunlocked.com/api/current/29.36,47.97?app_id=***********&app_key=***************"
                                                                                                               wget -O /Weather/WeatherOutput_`date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S`.json $url                                                                                       
flume-ng agent -f /apache-flume-1.5.2-bin/conf/Weather.conf -n agent1

Comment: I mean what does your crontab line look like and can you run it by hand?

Comment: @ joncon when i tried to run the script run.sh , it is running manually. but its not running when i tried to run it from crontab. the crontab contents are shown above in question.

Comment: the 'root run-parts' is meant to point to a directory and then run every script in that directory. You either need to create a directory, add run.sh to it and point run-parts to that directory or invoke the script directly  using  something similar to my answer, --without the 'root run-parts' line.

Comment: thanks for your reply i have changed that line to this in crontab                               #49 * * * * root /Weather/run.sh this running hourely. i dnt know how but crontab is running somehow, before it was not working.